# Voltage question

Tags: electrical

I’m in the US. How do I power a device with the following specs:

220-240 Volts/50-60 Hertz/58 Watts

European plug

Thanks in advance and please feel free to talk to me like I’m a moron, because I don’t have a clue. [image]

Thanks for the responses.

Long story on the type of device, but ... wife and I found a cider we loved in Ireland. Not available in US. Found a company in Belgium that sells 2-liter bottles of beer and cider, including the one we like (Orchard Thieves).

So it’s a keg-o-rator for 2-liter bottles of cider.

Pretty sure the tapper part works without power, so just need electric for it to chill the cider.

Comment: What *is* this device? Can you post photos of its label?

Answer (score 3):

Since you said generic "device", I have to give you a generic "works for everything" answer.  There might be other methods viable for particular devices.

### Install a 240V circuit

Yeah, America has those. They take double breakers, and are normally used for Big Stuff, but if you use one for Euro appliances, *I won't tell :)*

[image]

*That one is 60A, yours must be 15A (20A is allowable if the wire is #12).  Buy the correct breaker type for your panel!*

Then, install appropriate 240V sockets.  Note how they use the same boxes and cover plates as normal sockets.

[image]

Then change the plug on your appliance to a 6-15 plug.

Answer (score 2):

58 Watts - **easiest** way would be a 120V -> 240V "travel" transformer made for the purpose, with appropriate 120V 60 Hz plug and whatever sort of European receptacle you need (I gather there are multiple sorts, rather than a single standard.)

That becomes rapidly inconvenient/expensive at higher wattages. There are other approaches that can work in that case, but you're not in that case.

Comment: Absolute key here is that the device is rated for 50/60 Hz. Many are only 50 Hz and then it becomes a question of "is that because it really matters or is it just that they didn't bother to say it would work".

Comment: At 48W it'll probably be a europlug.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europlug